# How to prevent accidental deletion or move of folders/files in Mac?

Tags: macos, folders, trackpad

I have recently got a new Mac and keep accidentally moving folders around when using the trackpad and have managed to delete a couple folders as I am not used to this whole trackpad business. Is there a way to get a confirmation whenever a file/folder is moved or deleted in Mac to prevent this till i get more used to the trackpad?

Comment: BTW: one can select folders in the Trash and move them back (the systems knows about the original location)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to set yourself up a Standard User Account in System Preferences. Or maybe better is removing some of the multi-touch abilities in your System Preferences (such as disabling Tap to Click, Look up, or any setting you don't find particularly to your liking)

Setting up a Standard User (System Preferences > Users & Groups > "+" ) allows you to add a new person to your computer who doesn't have access to everything like a normal Administrator does.

In computer terms the hierarchy is Guest, then Standard, then Administrator, then Root. The Root is the computer itself and can do anything and everything it wants. Admins have similar flexibility with files and folders that belong to them but anything out of their reach requires a password. Standard accounts and Guests can do much with an Admins name and password, Guest files are typically deleted after logging out so what they do isn't meant to last. Consider these tips with a grain of salt and let us know if you need further help.